# ggplot2 histogram legend too large

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, legend, stackedbarseries

I'm pretty happy with the results I'm getting with R.  Most of my stacked histogram plots are looking fine, e.g.

[image]

and

[image]

However, I have a few that have  so many categories in the legend that the legend is crowing out the plot, e.g.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Here is my plot.r, which I call on the command line like this

```
RScript plot.r foo.dat foo.png 1600 800
```

foo.dat

```
account,operation,call_count,day
cal3510,foo-method,1,2016-10-01
cra4617,foo-method,1,2016-10-03
cus4404,foo-method,1,2016-10-03
hin4510,foo-method,1,2016-10-03
mas4484,foo-method,1,2016-10-04
...
```

entirety of foo.dat:  http://pastebin.com/xnJtJSrU

plot.r

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

args<-commandArgs(TRUE)

filename<-args[1]
png_filename<-args[2]

wide<-as.numeric(args[3])
high<-as.numeric(args[4])

print(wide)
print(high)

print(filename)
print(png_filename)

dat = read.csv(filename)

dat$account = as.character(dat$account)
dat$operation = as.character(dat$operation)
dat$call_count = as.integer(dat$call_count)
dat$day = as.Date(dat$day)

png(png_filename,width=wide,height=high)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=day, y=call_count, fill=account))
p <- p + geom_histogram(stat="identity")
p <- p + scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"), limits=as.Date(c('2016-10-01','2017-01-01')))

print(p)

dev.off()
```

Comment: You should consider removing the legend. It has more noise than information.

Comment: @slashdottir
where is the .csv file you are reading?

Comment: @aelwan it is passed in on the command line e.g. foo.dat

Comment: @aelwan added a few sample rows from csv

Comment: @PierreLafortune  That data has to be connected to the graph and shown in some way.  There are about 200 of these reports - all different - the ones without too many categories, the legend is appropriate.  Just some of them like the one shown are problematic

Comment: I think you should attach your whole dataset to be able to produce the same legend

Comment: @aelwan I can't, there is a limit to the size of the question.  Tried adding foo.dat and it wouldn't fit.

Comment: You can add it to Dropbox or Google drive and share the link if possible

Comment: oh right, duh, ok one sec

Comment: @aelwan ok, added, ty

Comment: You can place the legend underneath the plot `theme(legend.position="bottom")`

Comment: You can also specify the number of rows or columns of the legend `guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune I will give it a shot.  Thank you

Comment: @PierreLafortune  That is 1000% better  :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answer from @PierreLafortune

using:

```
p <- p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))
```

[image: much improved]